# AngularJS string splitting issue

Tags: javascript, string, templates, angularjs, split

I have data coming back in the following format

```
"yes | Yes no | No"
```

This string represents several things. As a whole, it represents a series of radio buttons. On the left side of the | is the actual value of the radio button. The right side is the label. This string thus represents the following:

Yes (value = yes)
No (value = no)

The string is stored several layers deep into an giant object, and thus, I need to be able to split the individual components up and use them while reliably maintaining the pattern of having the value first and the label second. Any suggestion on how I can achieve this using angular?

Answer (score 0):

In the service where the data comes back, you'll need to write a function to parse that and organize it. You COULD benefit from a custom filter, but its really not applicable here because filters are more traditionally meant for use on the view. This isn't really an angular question unless your question is broadly how to do it inside an angular app.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Fourth.  This doesn't feel like a truly "Angular" issue.  Its more of a javascript issue.  Anyway, here's my one-line solution (though its pretty hairy):

```
var fullString = "yes | Yes no | No";
var parts = fullString.split(/[ |]/).filter(function(str){ return str !== '';});
// parts is now ["yes", "Yes", "no", "No"]
```

And then you just use the values in the array to be your labels and values for your radio buttons.  Meaning, `parts[0]` is the value for the first radio button and `parts[1]` is the label.  I know its a pretty hairy solution, but whoever decided to encode the values of those radio buttons into a string that was poorly delimited with both spaces and vertical bars, they're the ones to blame.